# bash: export: `/home/mohin/.bashrc': not a valid identifier

Tags: terminal, ubuntu-16.04

When I Open my terminal, it showing this line.

```
bash: export: `/home/mohin/.bashrc': not a valid identifier
mohin@mohin:~$
```

I am using Ubuntu 16.04.

I used this line of commend after that I am facing this trouble

```
echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bashrc
source ~/.bashrc
```

I got this line from MEDIUM Post at the following link

https://medium.com/@rgdev/how-to-install-laravel-5-4-on-ubuntu-16-04-from-scratch-quickly-29375e18e7ca

I need to solve it. Please help me.

Comment: Please add the contents of your `.bashrc` to your question (removing anything sensitive)

Comment: I just follow the stapes of that link. I didn't anything more.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just fix this issue by the following process.

I did this commend:

```
mohin@mohin:~$ grep -i export ~/.bashrc
```

After That, It shows the following info

```
#export GCC_COLORS='error=01;31:warning=01;35:note=01;36:caret=01;32:locus=01:quote=01'
export PATH="$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin:$PATH"
export PATH="$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin:$PATH"
export PATH="$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin:$PATH" source /home/mohin/.bashrc 
export PATH="$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin:$PATH"
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin"
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.config/composer/vendor/bin"
```

over here I got the issue. I mean this line -

> export PATH="$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin:$PATH" source
>   /home/mohin/.bashrc

I open `.bashrc` and remove this line by the following command -

```
sudo nano /home/mohin/.bashrc
```

That's it. issue fix.