# export: `/home/khawar/.bashrc': not a valid identifier bash: !!: command not found

Tags: bash, terminal, gnome-terminal

When I open the Linux terminal then I got this error and I have no composer. Anaconda has been installed on my PC.

**Traceback**

```
bash: export: `/home/khawar/.bashrc': not a valid identifier
bash: !!: command not found
```

[image]

I got this line from StackOverflow Post at the following link

[bash: export: `/home/mohin/.bashrc': not a valid identifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49206220/bash-export-home-mohin-bashrc-not-a-valid-identifier)

I need to solve it. Please help me

**First Command**

```
grep -i export ~/.bashrc
```

**Traceback**

```
#export GCC_COLORS='error=01;31:warning=01;35:note=01;36:caret=01;32:locus=01:quote=01'
        export PATH="/home/${USER}/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
```

**Second Command**

```
grep -A 2 -B 2 -i export ~/.bashrc
```

**Traceback**

```
# colored GCC warnings and errors
#export GCC_COLORS='error=01;31:warning=01;35:note=01;36:caret=01;32:locus=01:quote=01'

# some more ls aliases
--
        . "/home/khawar/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
    else
        export PATH="/home/${USER}/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
    fi
fi
```

Comment: You normally source /home/khawar/.bashrc

Comment: I want to get rid of this error.

Comment: maybe an invalid line in your .bashrc file. can you try the following command and show  the results : `grep -i "/home/khawar/.bashrc" ~/.bashrc`

Comment: I just enter the command but no problem

Comment: I enterest this command grep -i export ~/.bashrc

Comment: did you provide all outputs of that command? if no please add the full output that got printed

Comment: yes, this command only print two lines.

Comment: ok maybe try the following, to include in the output  2 lines before and after the matched line: `grep -A 2 -B 2 -i export ~/.bashrc`

Comment: I updated an answer, please check it and give me answer

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to reset `bashrc` file and restart your computer. Then, we can easily solve this problem.

**Steps to solve**

```
cd ~
mv bashrc .bashrc.old
ll
cp /etc/skel/.bashrc ./
ll
```